# A form application throws System.NullReferenceException in the database if it is installed on another computer, but not on the development computer

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2017, compatibility, sql-server-express

Before getting into the subject, I would like to say that before getting to this problem I had to solve another one that I asked in the [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1321942/ensure-that-782-version-of-a-sql-server-express-lo).

Thanks to Erland Sommarskog, I think I have solved a part of the problem, but unfortunately not the whole problem.

So, this question is like a second part, therefore I put the previous one here in case this new problem I have could be a consequence of the previous one or of the solution to the previous one.

The program works on the laptop where I develop but not on other computers.

In the event viewer I have an Exception System.NullReferenceException that occurs because one of the methods tries to access the database and does not find it or an error is given.

[image]

Although it says that the guilty method is RecoverAffectedLanguage, actually I think the problem is here, because it is the part that is responsible of trying to connect (unsuccessfully) to the database.

The ExecuteReader() method

[image]

The connection string I have in the project is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\V782SQL;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory||Carboneria.mdf;Integrated  Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

I think I have it right so it will work on other computers (or well, enough so that, for some reason, it will work on the development laptop and only on that one).

And now, when I bring back the .mdf installed on the other computer and try to attach them in SQL Express 2014 I get this error:

> Error when searching for file XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (here the correct file path) in directories, operating system error: 5(Access denied.). (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)

At this point I have no more cards left to play. If it were that the database was always failing, even on my development computer, I could infer that there is some problem with the database itself, but right now, to my understanding, the solution does not lie there.

Comment: Well, if your connection open fails, the only thing your doing is returning null datareader -- which doesn't sound like a good idea. Maybe you should log or show the error you get in the try-catch?

Comment: I would like to avoid that, because after all the application is an inventory with an associated local database, there is no connection to a remote server. If it crashes at first when I have to start it and extract the first data, I'm screwed from the start.